# How to fix non-convergence in LogisticRegressionCV

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn to perform a logistic regression with crossvalidation on a set of data (about 14 parameters with >7000 normalised observations). I also have a target classifier which has a value of either 1 or 0.

The problem I have is that regardless of the solver used, I keep getting convergence warnings...

```
model1 = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(cv=10,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1,scoring='roc_auc',solver='newton-cg',penalty='l2')

/home/b/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py:285: LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge
  warn('The line search algorithm did not converge', LineSearchWarning)
/home/b/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/optimize.py:193: UserWarning: Line Search failed


model2 = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(cv=10,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1,scoring='roc_auc',solver='sag',penalty='l2')

max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
max_iter reached after 2 second

model3 = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(cv=10,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1,scoring='roc_auc',solver='lbfgs',penalty='l2')

/home/b/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:701: UserWarning: lbfgs failed to converge. Increase the number of iterations.
  warnings.warn("lbfgs failed to converge. Increase the number "

model4 = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(cv=10,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1,scoring='roc_auc',solver='liblinear',penalty='l2')

    cg reaches trust region boundary
iter 18 act 1.382e+06 pre 1.213e+06 delta 1.860e+01 f 7.500e+06 |g| 1.696e+06 CG   8
iter  2 act 1.891e+06 pre 1.553e+06 delta 1.060e-01 f 1.397e+07 |g| 1.208e+08 CG   4
iter  4 act 2.757e+04 pre 2.618e+04 delta 1.063e-01 f 1.177e+07 |g| 2.354e+07 CG   4
iter 18 act 1.659e+04 pre 1.597e+04 delta 1.506e+01 f 7.205e+06 |g| 4.078e+06 CG   4
cg reaches trust region boundary
iter  7 act 1.117e+05 pre 1.090e+05 delta 4.146e-01 f 1.161e+07 |g| 9.522e+05 CG   4
iter 31 act 1.748e+03 pre 1.813e+03 delta 2.423e+01 f 6.228e+05 |g| 5.657e+03 CG  14
```

What do I need to do to stop getting the warnings?

Comment: I wonder if this is a case of perfect or near [tag:separation].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can start by applying program's suggestion to increase `max_iter` parameter; but have in mind that it is also possible that your data simply can't be fit by a logistic model.

Comment: I had to bump max_tr up to 4000, but it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @user3188040 How long did it take you to run?

Comment: I'm a total newb at scikit. How do I "bump" max_tr (max_iter?) to 4000?

Comment: You can change max_iter value when creating a LogisticRegression object. 

model1 = linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(max_iter = 4000)

Comment: Apply `StandardScaler()` first, and then `LogisticRegressionCV(penalty='l1', max_iter=5000, solver='saga')`, may solve the issue. Using `L1` penalty to prioritize sparse weights on large feature space. Solver `saga`, only works with standardize data.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'solver' to 'sag' or 'saga'. This will increase to accommodate the larger numbers and remove the warning.